# I cannot view Wi-Fi networks on my VMware Kali machine

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux

I can connect my external wifi adapter to the machine via VM-removable devices and then connect the adapter to machine. But after this, i do not see any networks and my adapter doesn't show when running ifconfig.[image]

Comment: This is a setup issue, not a security issue.

Comment: This is *not* a security question. Check that your adapter is actually supported by the linux distro you're attempting to use.

Comment: Not a security question.  But you’ll need the errors from the system to diagnose (‘dmesg’ and ‘journalctl’)

Comment: Missing drivers.